# How to extends checkout-loader.js

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I am using magento 2.3.5-p2

I want to add an event without modifying the core codes of checkout-loader.js which are located here

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/checkout-loader.js`

I created a requirejs-config.js file in

`app/code/SR/ModifiedCheckout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

with content as below

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-loader': {
                'SR_ModifiedCheckout/js/checkout-loader': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

thus I created a new file at here

`app/code/SR/ModifiedCheckout/view/frontend/web/js/checkout-loader.js`

with content as below

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
 define([
    'rjsResolver',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery'
], function (resolver, customerData, $) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Initializes assets loading process listener.
     *
     * @param {Object} config - Optional configuration
     * @param {HTMLElement} $loader - Loader DOM element.
     */
    function init(config, $loader) {
        console.log("Init Checkout Loader");
        var product_name = 'n/a';
        var product_sku = 'n/a';
        var product_price = 'n/a';
        var product_brand = 'n/a';
        var product_category = 'n/a';
        var product_variant = 'n/a';
        var product_market_price = 'n/a';
        var product_wow_cashback = 'n/a';
        var product_shipping_wm = 'n/a';
        var product_shipping_em = 'n/a';
        var cart_items = customerData.get('cart')().items;
        var product_detail = {};
        var products = [];

        $(cart_items).each(function(index,productData){

            product_detail = {};

            product_name = productData['product_name'];
            product_sku = productData['product_sku'];
            product_price = productData['product_price_value'];
            product_brand = productData['product_brand'];
            product_category = productData['product_category'];
            product_variant = productData['product_variant'];
            product_market_price = productData['product_market_price'];
            product_wow_cashback = productData['product_wow_cashback'];
            product_shipping_wm = productData['product_shipping_wm'];
            product_shipping_em = productData['product_shipping_em'];

            product_detail = {
                'name':product_name,
                'id':product_sku,
                'price':product_price,
                'brand':product_brand,
                'category':product_category,
                'variant':product_variant,
                'quantity':productData['qty'],
                'dimension17':product_price,
                'dimension18':product_market_price,
                'dimension19':product_wow_cashback,
                'dimension20':product_shipping_wm,
                'dimension21':product_shipping_em,
            }

            products.push(product_detail);
        })

        dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'ecommerceCheckout',
        'eventDetails.category': 'Ecommerce',
        'eventDetails.action': 'Checkout Step 1',
        'eventDetails.nonInteraction': 'false',
        'ecommerce': {
            'currencyCode': 'MYR',
            'checkout': {
                'actionField': {
                    'step': 1
                },
                'products': products
                }
            }
        });
 
        // This code is not working , it will throw error checkout-loader.js:84 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_super')
        // this._super(config, $loader);
    }

    return init;
});
```

as you can see I tried putting

`this._super(config, $loader);`

but it throws an error

`checkout-loader.js:84 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_super')`

thus I am assuming that this is not the correct way of extending code to checkout-loader.js

please help if someone can help identify the problem to resolve this issue

any help is kindly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Finally able to solve this issue, the code need to be written this way

```
define([
    'rjsResolver',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery'
], function (resolver, customerData, $) {
    'use strict';

    return function (checkoutLoader) {

        var mixin = {

            gtmEventTrigger: function() {

                console.log("Init Checkout Loader");
                var product_name = 'n/a';
                var product_sku = 'n/a';
                var product_price = 'n/a';
                var product_brand = 'n/a';
                var product_category = 'n/a';
                var product_variant = 'n/a';
                var product_market_price = 'n/a';
                var product_wow_cashback = 'n/a';
                var product_shipping_wm = 'n/a';
                var product_shipping_em = 'n/a';
                var cart_items = customerData.get('cart')().items;
                var product_detail = {};
                var products = [];

                $(cart_items).each(function(index,productData){

                    product_detail = {};

                    product_name = productData['product_name'];
                    product_sku = productData['product_sku'];
                    product_price = productData['product_price_value'];
                    product_brand = productData['product_brand'];
                    product_category = productData['product_category'];
                    product_variant = productData['product_variant'];
                    product_market_price = productData['product_market_price'];
                    product_wow_cashback = productData['product_wow_cashback'];
                    product_shipping_wm = productData['product_shipping_wm'];
                    product_shipping_em = productData['product_shipping_em'];

                    product_detail = {
                        'name':product_name,
                        'id':product_sku,
                        'price':product_price,
                        'brand':product_brand,
                        'category':product_category,
                        'variant':product_variant,
                        'quantity':productData['qty'],
                        'dimension17':product_price,
                        'dimension18':product_market_price,
                        'dimension19':product_wow_cashback,
                        'dimension20':product_shipping_wm,
                        'dimension21':product_shipping_em,
                    }

                    products.push(product_detail);
                })

                dataLayer.push({
                'event': 'ecommerceCheckout',
                'eventDetails.category': 'Ecommerce',
                'eventDetails.action': 'Checkout Step 1',
                'eventDetails.nonInteraction': 'false',
                'ecommerce': {
                    'currencyCode': 'MYR',
                    'checkout': {
                        'actionField': {
                            'step': 1
                        },
                        'products': products
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

        };

        mixin.gtmEventTrigger();

        return $.extend(checkoutLoader, mixin);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a mixin to send analytics data? What I did, was to load a template through `checkout_index_index.xml`, which contains the js component. Inside the component, I import the customer-data component, and make sure to run the code only after the customer data is available. I also check that there are items in the cart before running any code.

```
var cartData = customerData.get('cart');

customerData.getInitCustomerData().done(function () {
    if (cartData().items && cartData().items.length !== 0) {
        //your code in here
    }
});
```